# AngularJS $scope vs this

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, scope, this

I'm beginner using AngularJS, and I have a question to ask.
I call a rest api to get comments by blog id, like following:

```
_getAllCommentsByBlogId(1, _convertComments);

function _getAllCommentsByBlogId(blogId, callback) {
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "/api/v1/blogs/" + blogId + "/comments"
    }).then(function(res) {
        // success
        callback(res.data);

    }, function(res) {
        // error
        console.log("Error: " + res.status + " : " + res.data);
    });
}
```

The response data is converted for view task, like following:

```
function _convertComments(response) {
    $scope.comments = convert(response);
}

function convert(array) {
    var map = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var obj = array[i];
        obj.children = [];
        map[obj.id] = obj;
        var parent = obj.parentId;

        if (!map[parent]) {
            map[parent] = {
                children : []
            };
        }
        map[parent].children.push(obj);
    }

    return map['0'].children;
}
```

After converting, i can view it as follows:

```
<div id="commentsApp"
  class="response-area"
  ng-app="commentsApp"
  ng-controller="CommentsController as c"
>
  <h2>3 RESPONSES</h2>

  <div>
    <script id="comments.template" type="text/ng-template">
      <div class="comment">
        {{comment.username}}
        <div ng-if="comment.showReply">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea autofocus class="form-control" row="3" ng-focus="c.showReply" ng-model="c.newComment.description"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="c.reply(comment)">reply</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="comment.showReply=false">cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ng-include src="'comments.template'" ng-repeat="comment in comment.children"></ng-include>
      </div>
    </script>
    <ng-include
      src="'comments.template'"
      ng-repeat="comment in comments"
    ></ng-include>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try changing following part in view

```
<ng-include
  src="'comments.template'"
  ng-repeat="comment in comments"
></ng-include>
```

into

```
<ng-include
  src="'comments.template'"
  ng-repeat="comment in c.comments"
></ng-include>
```

and following part in js

```
function _convertComments(response) {
    $scope.comments = convert(response);
}
```

into

```
function _convertComments(response) {
    this.comments = convert(response);    
}
```

then the view doesn't show anything. I already worked in this way and everything seems to work as expected.
Can you explain that?

I also read ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers) but my english is not good enough to understand it.
Thanks

Comment: Don't use callbacks with promise-based APIs. Use fat arrow (`=>`) functions in the `.then` method to bind the `this` context properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `this` inside some function in controller then it create its own context so its scope is different than outer scope which is actually a $scope.

So, best way to use this is, at the top of controller (starting of controller code) just define `var vm = this;` and then use `vm` everywhere where you're actually previously using $scope. This way you'll not encounter problems which you're facing now. (Btw on controller level scope you can still use `this`)
e.g.

```
var vm = this;
...
function _convertComments(response) {
    vm.comments = convert(response)
}
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DwkZ0S0Owml8sm1WNIf1?p=preview)** Example

Check out these simple explanations: [article1](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) , [article2](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax)

Comment: I change code as you suggest, and it works now, now I can understand it. By the way, here's the link about using vm https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/